# Creating and usage of new component

Tags: reactjs, import

I am having couple of components that are importing the same images and array.

Since I don't want to write and repeat the same thing in every component I want to create new component with imported images and array so I can just import that component instead all images every time.

**This is what I need in components:**

```
import img1 from '../assets/images/img1.jpg';
import img2 from '../assets/images/img2.jpg';

const images = [img1, img2, ....... ];
```

The thing is, when I create new component - Imported.jsx - with this imported images and array I am having errors with undefined images and so on....how can I achieve to do it ?

Comment: Are you using typescript?

Comment: No, I am using just react.